# Angular basic qustion about entity

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have custom form like this. it has input type defined like this.

```
input ng-name="prop.name" type="checkbox" ng-model="entity[prop.name]" ng-disabled="!prop.editable"
```

What does `entity[prop.name]` mean here, what does angular actually do? where does the entity gets defined?

Comment: if you did not define `entity` on the appropriate scope, angular knows nothing about it.

Comment: Lets say i define something like this in the directive, then what does entity:'=', mean? scope:{
            
      entity: '='
           },

Comment: Have a look at the [manual](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), especially the part at: *Directive Definition Object*. Also you can find some good introductory videos [here](http://www.egghead.io/)

Comment: The comment is a completly different question, you should clarify your initial question.